# Synthetic breathable fabrics vs natural fabrics for 'live-in' hiking clothing?

Tags: clothing

I'm putting together a kit list for hiking and the last time I went on a big hike I wore a breathable t-shirt, but I didn't find it that comfy and it also tended to start to smell quickly. Any tips on fabrics / garments for upper body when hiking long distance and multiple days?

Answer (score 23):

A lot depends on the climate, on your budget, and on how much you sweat on the move.

**Pros and cons of merino**

Merino is the king if you want to prevent odour and a good quality top can feel acceptably comfortable against the skin. It wicks quite well but holds around 25% more water than synthetics and takes around 50% longer to dry. Another issue is abrasion - if you wear a high wool content shirt directly under a pack you will quickly get holes in the shoulders and upper back. Finally, good wool garments can be expensive - keep an eye out for sales.

Because of the advantages of wool, researchers have been working hard to offset the disadvantages through blending with synthetics and through structural innovations such as grid weaves. One of the more interesting developments is [Power Wool](http://polartec.com/product/polartec-power-wool) from Maldon Mills.

**Pros and cons of synthetics**

Synthetics are cheaper and more durable, and wick even better - though if you sweat up in the cold (always a bad idea), there's a danger of flash chilling as moisture is drawn off your skin. A good synthetic is pleasant against the skin. Warmth for weight it is lighter than wool, and it dries more quickly. I personally find that with a good modern treatment the build up of odour is manageable, even on a long trek. But some users find that odour is more of an issue - this is something you have to try for yourself.

**A little known alternative - and my personal favourite**

A little known option is to wear a technical mesh such as [Brynje](http://www.journeymantraveller.com/2013/03/on-brynje.html) next to the skin capped by a lightweight wool or synthetic layer. This is essentially a sophisticated string vest and gives the best of all worlds. Although it's polypropylene it doesn't build up odour, at least in my experience, presumably because it's so well vented. In the cold, it traps a layer of warm air against your skin. When it's wet or sweaty it keeps the damp capping layer off your skin. And when it's hot, you can unzip the capping layer and dump heat instantly. It's widely used in Scandinavia, but has only recently been spreading to the UK and the US.

Comment: Forgot to mention bamboo, which has been attracting some attention. I've no personal experience, but it seems to sit between synthetics and merino in its properties. Reportedly, very pleasant to wear. The main problem seems to be that performance varies widely between manufacturers, and there's not yet an established brand which can be recommended.

Answer (score 2):

The odors probable came from your shirt clinging on to all the perspiration, and not having a chance to dry out.  If you can afford the weight of a spare (or sleeping) shirt, spring for it so your wet clothes can dry overnight.

It also helps to coordinate the rest of your clothing.  If you're sweating, make sure anything you're wearing over your baselayer will not impede the evaporation.  For windy ascents, a breathable windbreaker is ideal.

I recommend cotton only as the *outermost* layer if you plan to be near a campfire.  Synthetic materials do melt, even from stray embers.  Even then, it wouldn't be of much use since you would only wear it at camp or while sleeping.  Spring for wool if it's in your price range.

Comment: Letting your synthetic base layers dry overnight won't help much with odour. The bacteria that cause the smell will still accumulate.in the fabric. Cotton is OK in the desert but a very bad idea indeed in the wet and cold. It's sometimes used by woodcraft folk because it's safer near fire, but is not recommended for active use.

Comment: Correct, but bacteria won't thrive and multiply as much as they would in that moist environment.  If anything, it would mitigate the smell.  Good point that I forgot to include about the cotton - it should be strictly for camp/sleep.